# How do I find the latest record(s) in a mongo query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Suppose my collection `c` has records like this:

```
{ "_id": ..., "name":"foo", "date": "2020-02-02 ...", "value": 10 ...}
```

and I want to find, for each `name`, the *latest* (by `date`) record with a positive `value`.

Something like

```py
def find_latest():
    res = {}
    for d in c.find({"value":{"$gt":0}}):
        key = d["name"]
        try:
            if d["date"] > res[key]["date"]:
                res[key] = d
        except KeyError:
            res[key] = d
    return res
```

but the loop should be on the server side.

I suspect that it should be doable using [aggregation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html) but it appears that I would need to write JavaScript for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using aggregation, first match the desired value, then descending sort by date, use group to select the first document in the list for each name.  Since the list is sorted by date this will be the latest.

```py
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"value":{"$gt":0}}},
  {"$sort":{"date":-1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$name", "document":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$document"}} ])
```

(Note that this performs a lot better if you index `{value:1, date:-1}`

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please add an explanation (with links if possible) how it works? (I mean, things like `root` &c).

Comment: Also, this is phenomenally slow (15 sec to return 1.7k records from a 100k collection).

Comment: the index will make a world of difference